# Convert file to binary string with PHP

Tags: php, binary

I'm looking to convert a file to a binary string, preferably using PHP. Is this possible?

MORE INFO: I'd like to have users upload a small file through a form, and return the binary representation of that file as a binary string - i.e ones and zeros.

Comment: Literal '0's and '1's? Because all files are binary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$str = 'hello world';
$length = strlen($str);
$result = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $result .= str_pad(decbin(ord($str[$i])), 8, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
}

echo $result;
```

Comment: @mario: yep, missed that. Thanks

Comment: Thank you. Pointers are welcome, but a working example is great. I'll check it out and integrate it into my form. Thanks again.

Comment: can we change into string again?